# Pgfmath's height() fails with: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `H' (in 'height("H")')

Tags: pgfmath

The following code works as expected

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\usetikzlibrary{
  calc,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\fontHeight}{height("H")}
  \fill[red] (0, 0) circle (1pt);
  \fill[blue] ($(0, \fontHeight)$) circle (1pt);
  \node at($(.2, .5*\fontHeight)$) {H};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Letter 'H' with blue and red dot]

However, as soon as I plug it in my document's infrastructure, that is

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\input{common.tex}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\fontHeight}{height("H")}
  \fill[red] (0, 0) circle (1pt);
  \fill[blue] ($(0, \fontHeight)$) circle (1pt);
  \node at($(.2, .5*\fontHeight)$) {H};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

it fails with

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `H' (in 'height("H")').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...fmathsetlengthmacro{\fontHeight}{height("H")}
                                                  
[1]
```

It's a pretty large document and `common.tex` has a multiple includes. I know its a long shot, but maybe someone has some hints how to fix this.

Comment: Do you have a call of `babel` inside `common.tex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the error if I add

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

to your first example:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `H' (in 'height("H")').
```

Your actual language might be different.

The error vanishes if I add also

```
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot. I really owe you. Could you share how you figured that out?

Comment: @Flow Working crystal ball. Actually, been there, done that. 